# Using Gitlab as a yum repository?

Tags: gitlab, nexus, yum, data-migration

My customer is migrating off of Nexus (which has a yum repository), and they want to use Gitlab. I know Docker can hold docker images and JAR files via its maven feature. But does Gitlab allow you to host yum repositories as well? I wasn't able to find anything after some googling.

Comment: FYI - gitlab is working on this as a new feature: https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/5128

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store `rpm` packages (or `.deb`, etc.) in the Gitlab Registry, but there isn't official support for that package type so you'd have to use the "Generic" version. The downside to this is that you wouldn't be able to use the Gitlab Registry as a yum repo, however you could do something like:

```sh
#this downloads the package with filename `:filename:`
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/:project_id:/packages/generic/:package_name:/:package_version:/:filename:"

# Use rpm to install a package from a local file instead of a yum repo:
rpm -i :filename:.rpm
# For this use case, the file will have to be a .rpm file
```

The `-i` flag tells `rpm` to install the package. Another option is to `yum localinstall :filename.rpm:`.

Generic Packages must be enabled on your Gitlab instance (if you're using a self-hosted version).

Generic Packages docs are here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/generic_packages/#download-package-file

An example `.gitlab-ci.yml` file using Generic Packages is here: https://gitlab.com/guided-explorations/cfg-data/write-ci-cd-variables-in-pipeline/-/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml

Answer (score 0):

Check out OpenRepo: https://github.com/openkilt/openrepo

This is an open source package hosting server that can make packages available for both Debian (APT) and Red Hat (RPM) files.

In this case, you would configure your GitLab CI build to push your rpm files to the OpenRepo server.